# Tkinter table with SQL data

Tags: python, tkinter, pyodbc

I am trying to get a Tkinter table to show the records of a database. I can connect to the DB and use the standard print to console, and everything works fine. When I try to use a for loop to output to a Tkinter table, I am only getting the first result of my DB. I am also getting this error:

```
   File "C:\Users\Andrew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Andrew/PycharmProjects/GPSguidance/GPSGuidance.py", line 147, in database
    e.insert(END, Employees[j])
  File "C:\Users\Andrew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3051, in insert
    self.tk.call(self._w, 'insert', index, string)
_tkinter.TclError: wrong # args: should be ".!entry13 insert index text"
```

I believe it has something to do with my line of code with the insert function, but I've tried and I can't get it to work. Any help would be great! This table has 13 columns and 65 rows.

```
def database():
        window6 = tk.Tk()
        window6.title("Database Management")

        conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};'
                              'Server=ANDREW-PC\SQLEXPRESS;'
                              'Database=IowaDot;'
                              'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute('SELECT * fROM Employees')

`       i = 1
        for Employees in cursor:
            for j in range(len(Employees)):
                e = Entry(window6, width=20, fg='red')
                e.grid(row=i, column=j)
                e.insert(END, Employees[j])
            i = i + 1

        window6.mainloop()

``
```

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you verified that `Employees[j]` is a string and not `None`?

Comment: In the for loop, change `for Employees in cursor` to `for Employees in cursor.fetchall()`.

Comment: I have tried modifying the e.insert(END, Employees[j]) block of code, but I can't get it to work. If I take away the [j] and just put Employees, it gives me all the results but it is not organized. I did try the cursor.fetchall() and that did not change the output.

Comment: Have you verified that the data you're trying to insert is what you expect it to be? You need to first verify that the data is what you expect before trying to pass it to another function.

Comment: Alright, thanks. This is my first time importing SQL data into Python, I apologize for the lack of knowledge. I know that when I use just a print function and print to console, I get all 65 results from my data. The issue happens when I try to pass the data to the Tkinter window, and that's when I get that error. I get no errors when printing to console.

Comment: I did reference the attached question and was able to resolve my issue- THANKS! Here is what worked:            if Employees[j] is not None:
                e.insert(END, Employees[j])
            else:
                e.insert(END, "None")